# crucible init.d bash script

Tags: bash, init.d, atlassian-crucible

help me,please, to write crucible start/stop/status/restart init.d script
i/m beginer is bash-scripting,and the most problem with script it's how to check status

thanks

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

For a semi-official answer, see [How to start FishEye and Crucible at boot time on Linux](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHKB/How+to+start+FishEye+and+Crucible+at+boot+time+on+Linux).